# Getting the batch file to display numbers other than 0

Tags: windows, batch-file

Although, the batch file now displays a proper number for the damage, it only displays 0, no matter what. It seems to only ever generate 0 as its number.

Also, a second issue, if I can fix this, where and how should I put code to say `You have Lost!` or `You have Won` depending whether your health/the monster's health drops below 0.

Here is the new code:

```
@echo off
set phealth=20
set shealth=50
set pdamage=0
set sdamage=0
:start
cls
echo ===================
echo  Your HP:       %phealth% 
echo  Monster HP:    %shealth% 
echo ===================
echo Choices:
echo ===================
echo [1] Strike at the slime
echo [2] Back away
set /p choice=You choose option:
if '%choice%'=='1' goto :choice1
if '%choice%'=='2' goto :choice2
goto start

:choice1
cls
set /a pdamage=(%random% %% 5) + 1
set /a phealth=%phealth%-%pdamage%
set /a sdamage=(%random% %% 8) + 1
set /a shealth=%shealth%-%sdamage%
echo ===================
echo  Your HP:       %phealth% 
echo  Monster HP:    %shealth% 
echo ===================
echo You strike at the slime.
echo The slime strikes you back.
echo You took %pdamage% damage.
echo The slime took %sdamage% damage.
PAUSE
cls
goto start

:choice2
cls
set /a pdamage=(%random% %% 1) + 1
set /a phealth=%phealth%-%pdamage%
echo ===================
echo  Your HP:       %phealth% 
echo  Monster HP:    %shealth% 
echo ===================
echo You back away.
echo The slime strikes at you.
echo You took %pdamage% damage.
echo The slime took 0 damage.
PAUSE
cls
goto start

:end
```

Answer (score 0):

(%random% %% 1) will always returns 0

Put directly after the `cls` following `:start`

```
if %shealth% lss 0 echo You won&pause&goto :eof
if %phealth% lss 0 echo You lost&pause&goto :eof
```

Also:

If you are entering a string with a `set/p`, then there's no saying that the data entered doesn't contain <kbd>Spaces</kbd>. The way to get over that is to `"enclose the strings on both sides of the comparison operator in quotes"` - that is, double-quotes `'not single quotes'`

Comment: Thanks for that! Unfortunately,the random appears to generate 0 even if it is something like

    (%random% %% 24000) + 1

Also, the winning/losing bits cause a syntax error when the file is executed... Not sre why seeing as I did copy them exactly.

Comment: you didn't use `random` as a variable name somewhere, did you? (check with `set random`)